# Introducing a random effect in R glmer makes no difference vs glm - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have a logistic regression model that I was doing using the glm function in R. A reviewer commented that we needed to assess the impact of random effects. I used glmer, from R package lme4, to assess that, adding a random effects variable. But the estimates and standard errors of the fixed effect coefficients in the results of the glmer are identical to those of the glm, and the variance of the random effects variable is reported as zero - not something very low, but actually zero.

This makes me worry that I have not set up the model correctly.

The model has a logical result variable 'Script' that is regressed against five logical diagnostic indicators, five categories of treating doctor that are represented by four logical variables, one logical 'era' indicator, an integer age variable and a logical indicator of whether the patient has a certain blood marker.

The random effects variable used in the glmer model is a doctor ID, which will be one of the 59 treating doctors in the study. That was introduced because the reviewer was concerned about particular doctor effects that would cause the estimates of coefficient and their standard errors for the doctor category indicators to be inaccurate or biased because of varying propensities of individual doctors to give the prescription that is the Script result variable.

In setting up the model I had tried to follow the approach in Example 2 that is set out on this UCLA page 
(http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/melogit.htm), which has a fixed effects variable 'Experience' that is a property of a doctor, and a random effects variable DID (Doctor ID).

I speculated that perhaps the effect of the random effects variable disappeared if there were too many other explanatory variables. To test this out, I ran a slimmed-down model with only the four doctor category variables in it. That gave me a meaningful random effect variance. I then added more variables in a series of steps and found sure enough that the random effect variance decreased slightly with each added explanatory variable. Then it suddenly dived with the addition of a further explanatory variable (Btype1indic) from 0.08877 to 4e-14. I added one more explanatory variable (age_int, the integer age variable) and the variance went to zero.

Is it the case that the impact of a random effects variable, and its variance, decreases with the addition of each other fixed-effects variable to the model?

Why does the impact eventually go to zero, rather than just continuing to get smaller?

Should I be concerned that the fact that it goes to zero means I have done something wrong?

I attach below the output from my diagnostic runs. It shows the glmer output summaries as I add more variables at each step. I've inserted the marker '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++' next to the random effects variances to make them easier to spot and compare. The output includes a glm run at the end. It can be seen that the estimates and standard errors of the p-values are identical to those in the glmer run. The AIC is close but not identical, at 492.83 vs 494.8. I don't know what to make of that.

Thank you very much for any help that anybody can provide.

```
[1] "New mixed effects regression ####################################################################################"
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + (1 | DrID)
   Data: datatable

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   635.9    665.0   -311.9    623.9      947 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4896 -0.3776 -0.3099 -0.2397  4.4144 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DrID   (Intercept) 0.1006   0.3172  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Number of obs: 953, groups:  DrID, 59


Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.8762     0.3042  -9.454  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE   1.0657     0.3636   2.931  0.00338 ** 
DrIsCat2TRUE   1.3271     0.4152   3.197  0.00139 ** 
DrIsCat3TRUE   1.0939     0.6335   1.727  0.08423 .  
DrIsCat4TRUE   0.6739     0.3839   1.755  0.07920 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DIC1TR DIC2TR DIC3TR
DrIsCt1TRUE -0.815                     
DrIsCt2TRUE -0.680  0.564              
DrIsCt3TRUE -0.468  0.389  0.324       
DrIsCt4TRUE -0.772  0.642  0.534  0.368
[1] "New mixed effects regression ####################################################################################"
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + diag1 +      diag2 + diag3 + diag4 + diag5 + (1 | DrID)
   Data: datatable

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   552.5    605.9   -265.2    530.5      942 


Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8315 -0.3275 -0.2255 -0.1439  9.9103 


Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DrID   (Intercept) 0.09085  0.3014  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Number of obs: 953, groups:  DrID, 59


Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -3.7230     0.4197  -8.871  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE   1.4321     0.3835   3.735 0.000188 ***
DrIsCat2TRUE   1.6727     0.4476   3.737 0.000186 ***
DrIsCat3TRUE   1.5435     0.6737   2.291 0.021957 *  
DrIsCat4TRUE   0.8032     0.4084   1.967 0.049232 *  
diag1TRUE      1.3456     0.3149   4.273 1.93e-05 ***
diag2TRUE      0.7685     0.4147   1.853 0.063834 .  
diag3TRUE     -0.8395     0.3736  -2.247 0.024635 *  
diag4TRUE      1.6516     0.3897   4.238 2.25e-05 ***
diag5TRUE      2.6146     0.5224   5.005 5.59e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DIC1TR DIC2TR DIC3TR DIC4TR d1TRUE d2TRUE d3TRUE d4TRUE
DrIsCt1TRUE -0.694                                                        
DrIsCt2TRUE -0.611  0.559                                                 
DrIsCt3TRUE -0.434  0.398  0.327                                          
DrIsCt4TRUE -0.588  0.631  0.500  0.367                                   
diag1TRUE   -0.595  0.091  0.181  0.093 -0.040                            
diag2TRUE   -0.429  0.077  0.080  0.126  0.072  0.488                     
diag3TRUE   -0.419  0.034  0.078  0.065 -0.002  0.531  0.390              
diag4TRUE   -0.219  0.117  0.052  0.065  0.095  0.111  0.056 -0.053       
diag5TRUE   -0.230  0.149  0.137  0.110  0.101  0.166  0.070 -0.034 -0.081
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00293761 (tol = 0.001, component 1)


[1] "New mixed effects regression ####################################################################################"
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + diag1 +      diag2 + diag3 + diag4 + diag5 + old_era + (1 | DrID)
   Data: datatable

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   554.1    612.4   -265.0    530.1      941 


Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9335 -0.3276 -0.2212 -0.1427 10.1394 


Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DrID   (Intercept) 0.08877  0.2979  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Number of obs: 953, groups:  DrID, 59


Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -3.8135     0.4459  -8.552  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE   1.4295     0.3830   3.733 0.000189 ***
DrIsCat2TRUE   1.6774     0.4476   3.747 0.000179 ***
DrIsCat3TRUE   1.5380     0.6727   2.286 0.022243 *  
DrIsCat4TRUE   0.8001     0.4080   1.961 0.049864 *  
diag1TRUE      1.3563     0.3159   4.294 1.76e-05 ***
diag2TRUE      0.7908     0.4162   1.900 0.057388 .  
diag3TRUE     -0.7997     0.3790  -2.110 0.034831 *  
diag4TRUE      1.6524     0.3902   4.235 2.28e-05 ***
diag5TRUE      2.6130     0.5232   4.994 5.92e-07 ***
old_eraTRUE    0.1503     0.2354   0.638 0.523278    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DIC1TR DIC2TR DIC3TR DIC4TR d1TRUE d2TRUE d3TRUE d4TRUE d5TRUE
DrIsCt1TRUE -0.653                                                               
DrIsCt2TRUE -0.587  0.560                                                        
DrIsCt3TRUE -0.408  0.398  0.328                                                 
DrIsCt4TRUE -0.552  0.631  0.500  0.367                                          
diag1TRUE   -0.582  0.094  0.187  0.096 -0.038                                   
diag2TRUE   -0.432  0.078  0.085  0.127  0.072  0.491                            
diag3TRUE   -0.445  0.032  0.083  0.064 -0.003  0.532  0.398                     
diag4TRUE   -0.211  0.120  0.056  0.068  0.098  0.112  0.053 -0.051              
diag5TRUE   -0.220  0.151  0.139  0.111  0.103  0.167  0.071 -0.034 -0.080       
old_eraTRUE -0.332 -0.005  0.024 -0.009 -0.008  0.060  0.085  0.165  0.010  0.002
[1] "New mixed effects regression ####################################################################################"
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + diag1 +      diag2 + diag3 + diag4 + diag5 + old_era + Btyp1indic + (1 |      DrID)
   Data: datatable

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   498.0    561.1   -236.0    472.0      940 


Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.7047 -0.3053 -0.1857 -0.1201  7.6007 


Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DrID   (Intercept) 4e-14    2e-07   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Number of obs: 953, groups:  DrID, 59


Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -4.5004     0.4487 -10.029  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE     1.7184     0.3462   4.963 6.93e-07 ***
DrIsCat2TRUE     1.8158     0.4261   4.262 2.03e-05 ***
DrIsCat3TRUE     1.8923     0.6694   2.827 0.004699 ** 
DrIsCat4TRUE     1.0884     0.3813   2.855 0.004308 ** 
diag1TRUE        1.1332     0.3344   3.389 0.000702 ***
diag2TRUE        0.8158     0.4433   1.840 0.065732 .  
diag3TRUE       -0.6445     0.3931  -1.640 0.101083    
diag4TRUE        0.9052     0.4192   2.160 0.030808 *  
diag5TRUE        2.4063     0.5729   4.200 2.67e-05 ***
old_eraTRUE      0.3117     0.2493   1.250 0.211165    
Btyp1indicTRUE   2.0701     0.2692   7.690 1.47e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DIC1TR DIC2TR DIC3TR DIC4TR d1TRUE d2TRUE d3TRUE d4TRUE d5TRUE o_TRUE
DrIsCt1TRUE -0.618                                                                      
DrIsCt2TRUE -0.543  0.526                                                               
DrIsCt3TRUE -0.368  0.359  0.284                                                        
DrIsCt4TRUE -0.479  0.581  0.437  0.312                                                 
diag1TRUE   -0.588  0.108  0.220  0.098 -0.047                                          
diag2TRUE   -0.477  0.110  0.101  0.140  0.092  0.495                                   
diag3TRUE   -0.484  0.038  0.122  0.060 -0.022  0.550  0.408                            
diag4TRUE   -0.141  0.080  0.042  0.036  0.093  0.113  0.087 -0.007                     
diag5TRUE   -0.240  0.185  0.142  0.122  0.124  0.161  0.066 -0.046 -0.094              
old_eraTRUE -0.380  0.003  0.013  0.012  0.001  0.053  0.090  0.159 -0.013  0.052       
Btyp1ndTRUE -0.359  0.236  0.128  0.139  0.174 -0.041  0.028  0.035 -0.193  0.028  0.114
[1] "New mixed effects regression ####################################################################################"
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + diag1 +      diag2 + diag3 + diag4 + diag5 + old_era + Btyp1indic + age +      (1 | DrID)
   Data: datatable

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   494.8    562.9   -233.4    466.8      939 


Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9550 -0.3038 -0.1876 -0.1120  8.9225 


Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DrID   (Intercept) 0        0       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Number of obs: 953, groups:  DrID, 59


Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -5.33613    0.61104  -8.733  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE    1.42426    0.36618   3.890  0.00010 ***
DrIsCat2TRUE    1.40064    0.46032   3.043  0.00234 ** 
DrIsCat3TRUE    1.56801    0.68662   2.284  0.02239 *  
DrIsCat4TRUE    0.81990    0.39885   2.056  0.03982 *  
diag1TRUE       1.10406    0.33784   3.268  0.00108 ** 
diag2TRUE       0.80801    0.44417   1.819  0.06889 .  
diag3TRUE      -0.62696    0.39646  -1.581  0.11379    
diag4TRUE       0.83663    0.42577   1.965  0.04942 *  
diag5TRUE       2.37526    0.57865   4.105 4.05e-05 ***
old_eraTRUE     0.36109    0.25264   1.429  0.15293    
Btyp1indicTRUE  2.05930    0.27075   7.606 2.83e-14 ***
age             0.08512    0.03932   2.165  0.03040 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
[1] "New glm regression ####################################################################################"


Call:
glm(formula = Script ~ DrIsCat1 + DrIsCat2 + DrIsCat3 + DrIsCat4 + 
    diag1 + diag2 + diag3 + diag4 + diag5 + old_era + Btyp1indic + 
    age, family = binomial("logit"), data = datatable)


Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5459  -0.4202  -0.2630  -0.1578   2.9630  


Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -5.33613    0.61103  -8.733  < 2e-16 ***
DrIsCat1TRUE    1.42426    0.36617   3.890  0.00010 ***
DrIsCat2TRUE    1.40064    0.46031   3.043  0.00234 ** 
DrIsCat3TRUE    1.56801    0.68662   2.284  0.02239 *  
DrIsCat4TRUE    0.81990    0.39885   2.056  0.03981 *  
diag1TRUE       1.10406    0.33784   3.268  0.00108 ** 
diag2TRUE       0.80801    0.44416   1.819  0.06889 .  
diag3TRUE      -0.62696    0.39646  -1.581  0.11379    
diag4TRUE       0.83663    0.42577   1.965  0.04942 *  
diag5TRUE       2.37526    0.57865   4.105 4.05e-05 ***
old_eraTRUE     0.36109    0.25264   1.429  0.15293    
Btyp1indicTRUE  2.05930    0.27075   7.606 2.83e-14 ***
age             0.08512    0.03932   2.165  0.03040 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 644.28  on 952  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 466.83  on 940  degrees of freedom
AIC: 492.83


Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: How many observations are there per doctor? Possibly related questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/233987/36229 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/26677586/2954547

Comment: Here's the info for the 36 (out of 59) docs that had 10 obs or less each:          nbr obs per doc    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10 
                          freq              15    5    4    1    2    1    2    2    3     0. I tried to format this but it didn't work in the comment. There were 15 docs with only one ob, five with two, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to comment on your overall goal without data. But, the reason your random effects go down with adding more predictors is a consequence of explaining away doctor variance. For example, suppose that one of your doctors treats a large number of end-stage renal disease patients, who are very sick. Without end-stage renal disease as a fixed effect, that doctors random effect will likely be large to explain the outcomes of treating those sick patients. Whereas, if you add the fixed effect, you'll correctly adjust for these sick patients, and therefore reduce that doctors random effect.

Most likely you just don't have enough data to form more accurate predictions of your random effects.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate on the indistinguishable from zero using Wald' comment? I thought the reported variance was an estimate, so that even if the confidence interval around it included zero it would still show on the output as very small but nonzero. Are you saying that the reported variance is the lower bound of the confidence interval for the variance?

Comment: Rephrased. I have a feeling your number of observations is too small. It looks like you have around 1000 data points, with around 50 groups, giving you 20 per group, not good. Check out this answer for an explanation of why the random effect might be outright zero in this situation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/random-effect-equal-to-0-in-generalized-linear-mixed-model